# What do you call the apparatus you use to raise a flag?

Tags: word-request

What do you call the apparatus you use to raise a flag?

[image]

Here we see a dummy person raising the flag with an apparatus, what is the apparatus called? Is there a word for it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The wheeled part at the top is called a pulley. It is housed in a truck. The rope is a halyard, and where the rope is tied once the flag has been hauled into position is a cleat.

https://www.grandnewflag.com/flag-terminology/

There may be considerable regional variation in these terms. In the UK the 'snap hook' may be called an Inglefield clip:

The Inglefield clip (also known as a sister clip and a Brummel hook) is a clip for joining a flag or ensign quickly, easily and securely to flag halyards so that the flag can be hoisted.

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Inglefield_clip

https://www.hampshireflag.co.uk/Flagpole-Parts.htm